# Unity Still Requires Permissions After Changing Android Manifest

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

My Unity is completely updated.
I am attempting to create a game for Android. I used unity to develop the game, but I noticed that it was requiring the use of multiple permissions like reading phone state and the accounts of users. I changed the android manifest located in the Assets/Plugins/Android in order to remove these permissions, but the app is still requiring them. Below is the android manifest. What should I put in to stop Unity from requiring the permissions? To re-iterate, I would like to stop the use of the GET_ACCOUNTS and READ_PHONE_STATE permissions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.runefire.starfurious"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.04" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="22"
        android:targetSdkVersion="25" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.xiaomi.sdk.permission.PAYMENT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.xiaomi.permission.AUTH_SERVICE" />

    <application
        android:banner="@drawable/app_banner"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:isGame="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
            android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="reverseLandscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity"
                android:value="true" />
        </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.SkipPermissionsDialog" android:value="true"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="unity.build-id"
            android:value="b4d44a73-f11a-4d50-9a43-bf1b94c03bda" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="unity.splash-mode"
            android:value="0" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="unity.splash-enable"
            android:value="True" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.max_aspect"
            android:value="2.1" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitActivity"
            android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitTransparentActivity"
            android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitTransparentSoftwareActivity"
            android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitSoftwareActivity"
            android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" /> <!-- Xiaomi SDK Need -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.xiaomi.gamecenter.sdk.ui.MiActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="behind"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.xiaomi.gamecenter.sdk.ui.PayListActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.xiaomi.gamecenter.alipay.HyAlipayActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.xiaomi.account.openauth.AuthorizeActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.xiaomi.gamecenter.wxwap.HyWxWappayActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.alipay.sdk.app.H5PayActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|navigation|screenSize"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="behind"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
    </application>
```

Comment: The most important thing you missed to mention in this question is your Unity version.

Comment: PHONE_STATE is what unity uses to keep your game running in the background if someone calls, or you switch apps for a second. I wouldn't edit that permission out if you don't want your users to lose their place when their mom calls them.

Comment: Also, make sure to check every folder. ESPECIALLY if you downloaded assets to your game. It's common for assets that require a certain permission to create its own Android Manifest.